# How to use the same browser instance in a test class that calls methods from more than one page factory class?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, base-class, findby

I have two classes with selectors and methods (in both of them I declare the webdriver). I also use @findBy to select the locators.

Login Page with selectors and methods

```
package objectsAndMethods;

    public class LoginPage{
     public WebDriver driver;

     HomePage homePage = new HomePage();

     public void PageFactory(WebDriver driver){
      this.driver = driver;
     }

     //Login Page
     @FindBy(id = "id") private WebElement userName;
     @FindBy(id = "id1") private WebElement password;
     @FindBy(id = "id2") private WebElement loginButton;

     Parameters Parameters = new Parameters();

     public void navigateToPage() {
      driver.navigate().to(Parameters.getBaseUrl());
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
     }

     public void fillUsername(){
      userName.clear();
      userName.sendKeys(Parameters.getUsername());
     }

     public void fillPassword(){
      password.clear();
      password.sendKeys(Parameters.getPassword());
     }

     public void clickLoginButton(){
      loginButton.click();
     }

     public void checkUserLogged(){
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id")));
     }
    }
```

Home Page - with selectors and methods

```
public class HomePage {
      @FindBy(id = "id") private WebElement logoutButton;
      @FindBy(id = "optionId") private WebElement selectOption;

      @FindBy(xpath="/xpath") private WebElement submitButton;
     public WebDriver driver;

      public void selectOption(){
       Select droplist = new Select(selectOption);   
       droplist.selectByVisibleText(Parameters.getOption());
      }         
      public void clickSubmitButton(){
       submitButton.click();
      }
    }
```

BASE TEST CLASS - setUp + login + tearDown

```
package baseClasses;

    public class BaseClassTest{


     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     @Before
     public void setUp() {
      loginPage.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     }

     LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();

     @Test
     public void loginTestCase() throws IOException, InterruptedException {


      loginPage.navigateToPage();
      System.out.println("You are on " +                baseClasses.Parameters.getBaseUrl());
      Thread.sleep(2000);

  LoginPage loginPageFindBy = PageFactory.initElements(loginPage.driver, LoginPage.class);

  loginPageFindBy.fillUsername();
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  loginPageFindBy.fillPassword();
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  loginPageFindBy.clickLoginButton();
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  loginPage.checkUserLogged();
  System.out.println("User is logged");
 }

 @After
 public void tearDown() {
  loginPage.driver.quit();
 }
```

HomePageTest - test class

```
  public class HomePageTest extends BaseClassTest{

     //setUp();
     HomePage homePage = new HomePage();


     @Test
     public void homeTestCase() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      super.setUp();
      super.loginTestCase();

      HomePage homePageFindBy = PageFactory.initElements(homePage.driver, HomePage.class);


      homePageFindBy.selectOption();
      Thread.sleep(2000);

      homePageFindBy.clickSubmitButton();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
     }
    }
```

HomePage test calls methods from 2 classed (Login Page and Home Page) - both of them having drivers declared.
The thing is that when running the test, 2 firefox instances open and only the Login Test is successfully executed, the other methods from HomePage fail.
Can someone help me understand what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `HomePageTest` the method `setUp()` under `@Before` annotation in `BaseClassTest` is being called before `homeTestCase()` since `HomePageTest` extends `BaseClassTest`.

The line `loginPage.driver = new FirefoxDriver();` opens the first browser. When you call `super.setUp();` `setUp()` is excuted again and second browser is opened.

Just remove `super.setUp();` from `homeTestCase()`.

Comment: I've tried this, but still doesn't work. It still opens 2 browsers and still the first test (BaseClassTest) is ok executed and the HomePageTest fails and no methods within it are executed.